# How to draw the following graph in R? And what are these types of graphs called?

Tags: r, ggplot2, charts, graphics, data-visualization

I am trying to present the following data

```
x <- factor(c(1,2,3,4,5))
x
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5
value <- c(10,5,7,4,12)
value
[1] 10  5  7  4 12
y <- data.frame(x, value)
y
  x value
1 1    10
2 2     5
3 3     7
4 4     4
5 5    12
```

I want to convert the above information into the following graphical representation

[image]

What is the above type of graphs called. I checked out dot plot, but that only stacks vertically.

Comment: `?geom_dotplot`

Comment: Additionally there's similar aesthetic qualities in the plots made by https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This solution plots sets of three bar graphs facetted by `x`. The height of the bars within each set is determined using the remainder from dividing `value` by 3. Horizontal spacing is provided by natural geom spacing. Vertical spacing is created using white gridlines.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
```

## Data

```
dataset <- data.frame('x' = 1:5, 'value' = c(10, 5, 7, 4, 12))
```

Since every `value` is supposed to be represented by three bars, we will add 3 columns to the dataset and distribute the magnitude of the `value` among them using integer division:

```
dataset[, c('col1', 'col2', 'col3')] <- floor(dataset$value / 3)
r <- dataset$value %% 3
dataset[r == 1, 'col1'] <- dataset[dataset$value %% 3 == 1, 'col1'] + 1
dataset[r == 2, c('col1', 'col2')] <- dataset[r == 2, c('col1', 'col2')] + 1
```

Now, we will melt the dataframe for the purposes of plotting:

```
dataset <- melt(dataset, id.vars = c('x', 'value'))
colnames(dataset)[4] <- 'magnitude' # avoiding colnames conflict
dataset$variable <- as.character(dataset$variable) # column ordering within a facet
```

## Plot

First, we will make a regular bar graph. We can move facet labels to the bottom of the plot area using the `switch` parameter.

```
plt <- ggplot(data = dataset)
plt <- plt + geom_col(aes(x=variable, y = magnitude), fill = 'black')
plt <- plt + facet_grid(.~x, switch="both")
```

Then we will use `theme_minimal()` and add a few tweaks to the parameters that govern the appearance of gridlines. Specifically, we will make sure that minor XY gridlines and major X gridlines are blank, whereas major Y gridlines are white and plotted on top of the data.

```
plt <- plt + theme_minimal()
plt <- plt + theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
                   panel.grid.major.y = element_line(colour = "white", size = 1.5),
                   panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                   panel.ontop = TRUE)
```

We can add `value` labels using `geom_text()`. We will only use `x` values from `col2` records such that we're not plotting the value over each bar within each set (`col2` happens to be the middle bar).

```
plt <- plt + geom_text(data = dataset[dataset$variable == 'col2', ], 
                       aes(label = value, x = variable, y = magnitude + 0.5))
plt <- plt + theme(axis.text.x=element_blank()) # removing the 'col' labels
plt + xlab('x') + ylab('value')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will do a graph similar to the one in the question.
I had to change the data.frame, yours was not fit to graph with `geom_dotplot`. The new variable `z$value` is a vector of the values `1:5` each repeated as many times as `value`.

```
library(ggplot2)

value <- c(10, 5, 7, 4, 12)

z <- sapply(value, function(v) c(1, rep(0, v - 1)))
z <- cumsum(unlist(z))
z <- data.frame(value = z)

ggplot(z, aes(x = jitter(value))) +
  geom_dotplot() +
  xlab("value")
```

[image]